# encrypt and decrypt with diacrits

Tags: php, encryption, cryptography

I have these code for encrypt and decrypt.

[image]

It works good for text (for example: "This is a text"), which is withnout diacritics (that means without : ěščřžýáíéúů).
But I need encrypt and decrypt text with this special letters (with : ěščřžýáíéúů).

Can somebody help me, please?

Thank so much for every answer and help.

Have a nice day. M.

```
define ("ENCRYPTION_KEY", "QaY7e4d1c");
$string= "This is a text"; // -> this work alright 
//$string= "áýžřčšě";  I NEED THIS TEXT ENCRYPT AND DECRTYPT
echo $encrypted = encrypt($string, ENCRYPTION_KEY);
echo "<br />";
echo $decrypted = decrypt($encrypted, ENCRYPTION_KEY);
function encrypt ($pure_string,$encryption_key)
{
$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH,MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size,MCRYPT_RAND);
$encrypted_string =             mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH,$encryption_key,utf8_encode($pure_string),MCRYPT_MODE_ECB,$iv);
return $encrypted_string;
} 
function decrypt ($encrypted_string,$encryption_key) 
{
$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH,MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size,MCRYPT_RAND);
$decrypted_string =     mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH,$encryption_key,$encrypted_string,MCRYPT_MODE_ECB ,$iv);
return $decrypted_string;
}
```

Comment: image will not help too much please type  your code.

Comment: I add code to end of my question.

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt had many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution and are being maintained and is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `utf8_encode` in your encryption function, but not calling `utf8_decode` when you decrypt, so your functions as they stand don't complement each other.

I'd recommend removing the call to `utf8_encode` entirely. `mcrypt_encrypt` doesn't care what encoding your string uses, so whatever you pass in will be what you get back out. Your script works fine for me if I remove it:

```
$encrypted_string = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $encryption_key, $pure_string, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
```

I'd also suggest reading this: https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/if-you-re-typing-word-mcrypt-into-your-code-you-re-doing-it-wrong

Comment: Thanks so much...You helped me so much. I removed utf8_endoce and I add into <head> <meta charset="utf-8"> and it works how I need...